# How can i create a login page separately from my other single page application in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have created a single page application with reactjs, I have a 'get in touch' page where i can get customer informations, i need to create a login page what will allow admin only to view customer information but this page should be separated with other pages, Meaning that for example i have a login button i need when a click it to send me in a login form, here is a link of the project and  i have attached my code on how i tried to work out with it, but not succeeded. Please i will appreciate anyone who will help me to to get through this.
https://hakikazi-lawfirm.netlify.com/

My App.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Login from './Components/Login/Login'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Navbar from './Components/NavBar/Navbar';
import Slider from './Components/Slider/Slider';
import About from './Components/About/About';
import Service from './Components/Services/Service';
import Team from './Components/Team/Team';
import Promo from './Components/Promo/Promo';
import Testimonial from './Components/Testimonials/Testimonial';
import Contact from './Components/Contact/Contact';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Navbar/>
      <Slider/>
      <About/>
      <Service/>
      <Team/>
      <Promo/>
      <Testimonial/>
      <Contact/>
      <Footer/>
     <Router>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} /> 
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}
```

My

Comment: For starters, your Login link doesn't go to `/login` it goes to `/#login` which looks for an html id of "login" on the page.

Comment: @ZekeHernandez i have changed to /login but what happen my login form appear at the bottom of the page as the order of my component from the App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off writing it this way;

```
function MainWebsite() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Navbar/>
      <Slider/>
      <About/>
      <Service/>
      <Team/>
      <Promo/>
      <Testimonial/>
      <Contact/>
      <Footer/>

    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} /> 
          <Route path="/" component={MainWebsite} /> 
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App
```

so the App component will decide with the switch or your own kind of condition what should load at what time. in my example am using the paths to decide what to load. but you can equally write it using conditions or any other methods.

Let me know if this worked. Happy to help to the end.

Comment: @mv509 your solution worked it is taking me to a login page as i wanted, thank you so much